# Unable to start new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i wrote this command to create a new rails project

```
rails new My_project
```

and every thing works fine except that error message in the end (scroll down please)

```
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install --local
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:326:in `bundle_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:342:in `run_bundle'
from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

and i tried to access to rail by

```
rails server
rails s
```

and this error message came out

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/aseer/Documents/brojects/plog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

what should i do?
+ excuse my English please.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed bundler?

```
gem install bundler
```

If not, try this

Comment: thanks! it almost works but this message came out "/usr/bin/ruby2.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/usr/bin/ruby2.1: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)" is theres somthing else i've to install?

Comment: also when i tried to write "rails server" this message came out: "Could not find gem 'rails (= 4.1.8) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

Comment: Then `bundle install` would be the next logical step. Have you created Gemfile?

Comment: Gem:Ext:BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r./siteconf20151001-14586-2dqlz6.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h extconf failed, exit code 1Gem files will remain installed in/tmp/bundler20151001-14586cgb8gwjson-1.8.3/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.Results logged to /tmp/bundler20151001-14586-cgb8gwjson-1.8.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.outAn error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling

Comment: then i tried installing json and that what happend: ERROR:  Error installing json:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20151001-17755-2v6aj1.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

Comment: Gemfile? i don't think so, how can i create one? i'm sorry for wasting your time sir, i really appreciate your help

Comment: No prob man :) To make it short: Bundler is the best practice way to manage dependencies for ruby applications. Gemfile is a file, describing these dependencies. How to create it, see http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html. Note, that for many PaaS offerings, like Heroku or OpenShift, having Gemfile/Gemfile.lock is a mandatory requirement to deploy you app there. Otherwise they have no idea what is the environment you maintain locally on your developer machine. Maybe a bit oversimplified, but still :)